# Sharing scope object with child directive scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a parent directive which creates an instance of a third party object during `link` and that variable needs to be accessible to child directives.

However, there are two limitations:

- There can be multiple instances of this per-page, so a singleton at the top of the javascript file won't work.
- The child directives are recursive, so they have to create their own scope.

The only way I can think of is to pass that value as an attribute to each child directive. That feels inefficient but given the above constraints, I don't see any alternative.

```
// Some imaginary third-party object
function Tree() {}

// Root directive which creates an instance of the object, links to the page, and loads the data needed.
app.directive('tree', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><nodes nodes="nodes"></nodes></div>',
        scope: {
          nodes: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, $element) {
           // This value needs to be accessible to all child directives
           scope.tree = new Tree();
        }
    };
});

// A directive to render an array of nodes
app.directive('nodes', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<ol>' +
            '<li ng-repeat="node in nodes track by node.id">' +
                '<node node="node"></node>' +
            '</li>' +
        '</ol>',
        scope: {
            nodes: '='
        }
    };
});

// A directive to render a single node, and recursively any child nodes
app.directive('node', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            node: '='
        },
        template: '<div><span ng-bind="node.text"></span></div>',
        link: function(scope, $element) {
            if (scope.node.children && scope.node.children.length > 0) {
              console.log(scope.node.children);
                var tmpl = '<nodes nodes="node.children"></nodes>';
                var children = $compile(tmpl)(scope);
                $element.append(children);
            }

            // @todo Here's a good example of where I need access to scope.tree
        }
    };
}]);
```

The only solution I can think of is adding `tree: '='` to the `scope` objects and then passing in `tree="tree"` to each child.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RptA3ene4beuP9ulCpzj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to not isolate the scope, and that way the child directives would inherit from their parent scope. If the parent has `scope.tree = new Tree()` then the nested directives would inherit `scope.tree`.

However, since you mentioned that there can be multiple instances of this per page, that means you probably need an isolated scope (which is what you currently have). The only way to pass data into an isolated scope is through the directive attributes in the markup.

I think you answered your own question :)

Comment: The other issue is that I need isolate scopes bound to the attributes because these are recursive directives, I can't keep re-assigning the scope arrays.